# Error in png while knitting HTML

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I'm new to this so let me know if there's anything else I need to add for you to help me with this problem.  I'm a student and the files I'm using are being pulled from my professor's files online.

While trying to knit HTML on Rstudio I get an error.  Everything runs fine for a while up until a few lines from the end.  At first I thought it was a windows 10 problem (because that's initially what I ran it on) but it happened on a Mac as well.  Any ideas to what could be causing this? The following are the lines it stops on.  {r} being line 239 and source... being 240. 241 is open.  Is this as simple as a broken link?

`{r}
source("../10 ListsForIfFunctionsPng/ListsForIfFunctionsPng.R", echo = TRUE)`

```
< * Closing connection 0 Quitting from lines 240-241 (RWorkshop.Rmd)
Error in
png("/Users/pcannata/Mine/UT/GitRepositories/DataVisualization/RWorkshop/00
Doc/categoricals.png", : unable to start png() device Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval-> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> png Execution halted
```

Comment: Cannot debug this without at the very least the lines that cause the problem! If you can strip your Rmd to a minimal working example (that reproduces your problem), that would help matters greatly.

Comment: I don't think `/Users/pcannata/....` looks like a normal path under Windows. If you start `png()` on an invalid path, you will definitely fail. Like the comment above, there is no answer without a minimal self-contained reproducible example.